# Any robust method to sort file columns?

Tags: perl, sorting, system-calls, csv

I have a Perl script using a `system` call to sort a tsv file:

```
system("sort -k8 -r -n -t \$'\t' in.txt > out.txt");
```

It works fine in CentOS and SUSE Linux. But in Ubuntu, it gives an error:

```
sort: multi-character tab `$\t'
```

It seems the problem with different OS interpret the quote differently. Do you have a simple but more robust method to sort a tsv file in Perl?

Comment: I'll bite: Why are you using the system sort command instead of the internal Perl sort command? The Perl sort will be faster, more efficient, and will work on all operating systems -- even Windows.

Comment: David, I was thinking loading the file to array, sorting it and then write it out. This is cumbersome. Additionally, sorting the file is not a bottle-neck in my program so I just take the easy way. Or do you have a simple and efficient way? Thanks.

Comment: The difference is that ubuntu's `/bin/sh` is dash, not bash. `$'\t'` is a bashism.

Comment: @DavidW. what makes you think perl sort will be faster? the system sort is very fast and not limited to in-memory data set sizes. Perl is not a speed demon, it's an HLL with substantial overhead compared to programs written at a lower level of abstraction.

Comment: @dberhur There have been several posts about the [speed of Perl's sorting algorithm vs. the command line sort](http://peeterjoot.wordpress.com/2010/06/22/comparing-some-times-for-perl-vs-sort-command-line-hacking/). If OP wrote his own C sort program for this particular situation, it would be faster than Perl, but the Unix sort command is written for flexibility. I've been surprised at Perl's speed when compared to what I thought were simple compiled Unix system commands.

Comment: @ken Over the years, I've discovered that when you rely upon Perl's `system` command to do something you thought would be simple, it usually turns out not to be simple. I've been burned so many times by using Unix commands like `date`, `mailx`, and yes, even `sort` in my Perl scripts. As you discovered, even two Linux boxes don't quite work the same way when accessing the same GNU `sort` command. What are the chances your program will work on a Mac which is BSD based? Or Solaris or HP/UX? The 10 minutes it takes to do it in Pure Perl is shorter than the hours debugging that "simple" solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, you'd use an array invocation of `system` to avoid the shell, but you have I/O redirection in the command, which is fiddly to deal with.  OTOH, `sort` allows you to specify the output file with `-o`, and the named file could be one of the inputs (though it won't be here):

```
my @cmd = ( "sort", "-k8", "-rn", "-t", "\t", "-o", "out.txt", "in.txt" );

system(@cmd);
```

The shell is not invoked; the tab is not mangled.  I combined the `-r` and `-n` options into one; you could leave them separate if you prefer, or (at a pinch) add them after the `-k8` option.

Comment: beautiful, this way works well for this sort command. But what happen if I want to pipe the input from another output? Is creating another temporary file is the only option? Also, what happen if the command doesn't have the output option and I can't use redirect (>)? Any suggestion for this 2 cases? Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you want to pipe to or from the `sort` command (or both), or if the target command doesn't have a convenient `-o`-like option, you have to work harder on your IPC (inter-process communication) mechanisms, and you have to abandon `system` and use (on Unix) `fork` and `exec`, etc.  Plus plumbing.  It can be done; you'd be well advised to look at the IPC modules in Perl, though, to save you effort.  The other main alternative is the one suggested by David W: do the sorting in Perl itself.  You need to know what you're about, but it is also doable and avoids temporary files.

Comment: I got "Input file specified two times." error with cygwin

Comment: @arjun: When you did what?  The command shown in my answer seems unlikely to generate that error.

Comment: actually I was debugging using eclipse and got the error. I don't know the reason why? There is no issue/error with  your command when ran from cywin.